# Склеивание полигонов в Yandex API

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi

В Yandex APi JS допустим когда сначала рисуешь один полигон затем рядом еще один полигон предусматривается автоматическое "cклеивание" границ полигонов ,чтобы небыло лишних пустых областей между границами?см скриншоты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://github.com/topojson/topojson

Comment: а это что?я понимаю что это список программ так и где могу найти программу и ответ по автоматическому склеиванию?

Comment: это формат, я не знаю поддерживают ли его яндекс карты, но он как раз решает проблему дублирования границ соседних стран, и есть средства, которые могут из geojson получить topojson

Comment: я вообще говорю о произвольных областях когда админ/лаборант рисует в админке произвольный полигон потом рядом еще полигон тоже произвольный,главное чтобы лишних областей между границами не было ,а вы говорите административные области как границы

Comment: Ну я считаю что это схожая проблема, административная граница лишь понятный  пример

Comment: а где прверить это там список Simplification или Manipulation какую выбрать для проверки?а Вы экспериментировали со склеиааниями?

Comment: еще вот тут посмотрите https://turfjs.org/, я конкретно Вашу задачу не решал, но приходилось ковыряться около таких, simplify - это уменьшение числа точек без видимого изменения линии, Вам нужен какой нибудь overlap из turf.js или что-то еще, я сейчас на работе не могу этому время уделить, возможно попозже отвечу

Comment: Хорошо, как освободитесь,напиши пожалуйста,буду благодарен!!есть на случай скайп у Вас?

Comment: нет, я не использую скайп, можете написать комментарий тут начинающееся c @StrangerintheQ и я получу уведомление